# Clear iOS 6 <input type=file> image thumbnail

Tags: javascript, ios, ios6

Since iOS 6 it is possible to use the `<input type='file'>` to access the photo library. I use this to upload images to a wall, through an UIWebView. Works fine.

The input element is kinda nicely implemented by Apple, with a small auto-generated thumbnail between the button and the filename field.

My only problem around this is that I cannot seem to reset this thumbnail. If it set the `.value` of the input to null, the filename clears out ("no file selected", as stated initially) but the thumbnail remains. Same thing if I try to `.reset()` the html form encapsulating the input. The small image won't go away!

Anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Seems like someone should file a bug report.

Comment: Well, yeah. Maybe that is the case, that this isn't thought of by Apple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to have reset work on the containing form. I just did a simple test on my device using webkit inspector attached to it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>upload</title>
    <style>
    html, body {
        width: 300px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<form id="con">
<input id="tgt" type="file" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I used the simple html above, then the following javascript in the inspector:

```
var con = document.getElementById('con');
con.reset();
```

Using that removed the thumbnail image for me. I've included an example with inline code here:
http://www.mixicon.com/downloads/input.html

Comment: As an aside, I used iOS 6.1.1 (10B145) to test this.
appVersion: "5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10B145 Safari/8536.25"

Comment: Suppose they've fixed this issue by now. Thanks for noticing me!